# Cambiar de base datos usando variable @databaseNombreVariable

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

¿Como cambiar de base de datos con el nombre de la base guardada en variable?; Realice el siguiente codigo sin embargo no cambia de base de datos.

```
DECLARE @inicio VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @bdname VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @usedb VARCHAR (100)

    SET @inicio = (
    SELECT 
        MIN(dbid)
        FROM 
        sysdatabases
        WHERE name IS NOT NULL 
        and name not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB'))

    SET @bdname = (
    select name from sysdatabases
    where dbid = @inicio )
    print @bdname

SET @usedb = 'USE ' + @bdname
EXEC (@usedb)
GO
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de SQL Server usas?

Comment: Utilizo la versión  SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando `sysdatabases` que actualmente se encuentra obsoleto, para obtener información (con los permisos necesarios) de las base de datos que se encuentran en tu servidor debes usar [`sys.databases`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql).

Ahora, hay otro punto que debes considerar. Revisemos:

```
USE master;

DECLARE @bdname VARCHAR(100);
SELECT TOP 1
    @bdname = name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name IS NOT NULL
      AND name NOT IN ( 'master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'ReportServer'
                         ,'ReportServerTempDB'
                      )
ORDER BY database_id;

SELECT DB_NAME() [BD FUERA DE EXEC];

EXEC (N'
SELECT DB_NAME() [BD EN EXEC];

USE [' + @bdname + '];

SELECT DB_NAME() [BD EN EXEC];
'    );
GO

SELECT DB_NAME() [BD FUERA DE EXEC];
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +------------------+
> | BD FUERA DE EXEC |
> +------------------+
> | master           |
> +------------------+
>
> +------------+
> | BD EN EXEC |
> +------------+
> | master     |
> +------------+
>
> +------------+
> | BD EN EXEC |
> +------------+
> | BD_INICIAL |
> +------------+
>
> +------------------+
> | BD FUERA DE EXEC |
> +------------------+
> | master           |
> +------------------+
> ```

Podrás observar que el cambio que realices de forma dinámica solo ocurrirá en el contexto que se encuentra dentro del [EXECUTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/eS-Es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql).

---

**Referencia:**

- [System Information in SQL Server 2000 vs SQL Server 2005](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1037/system-information-in-sql-server-2000-vs-sql-server-2005/)
- [DB_NAME (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql)